# Working on getting GPS to start when a widget is pressed

Tags: android, gps

After following a tutorial on SO I found a way to get GPS to enable after a person goes into my app. The issue being is that I have the code set up to change the display for lat and lon to change as the user changes position. I know it works because I have my first GPS running smooth. Right now I am trying to implement it on my existing code.

Aside the point when I run the code the GPS Icon flashes like it working but when I go into the app nothing changes.

Here is the code I was using:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent("android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE");
    intent.putExtra("enabled", true);
    sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Any tips on getting this to fully function please do tell!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better solution to your problem is to ask user to enable GPS himself. Doing it without user's permission can be pretty harmful, imagine that a device's battery is almost empty and enabling GPS will kill the battery right away. To ask user to enable GPS you can fire an `AlertDialog`, create an `Intent` with the `ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS` to open the device's Settings menu, where the user will be able to enable GPS. Hope this helps.